# Displaying TextBox and Label when CheckBox selected in RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I had my list of data displayed on RadioButtonList.
It is not radio button but it's radio button list.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList Font-Size="X-Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioBtn_SelectedIndexChange" onclick="ShowHide(this)"  RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="2" ID="rediobtn" runat="server">
```

[Radiobuttonlist display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W24M.png)

What I want to do now is to display a QTY TextBox where I can enter the amount and submit it into the database.

So I created them:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbrQty" Text="QTY" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="textQtyInput" runat="server" Visible="false"  />
```

In the code behind I want to know how to code so that it could detect a RadioButton is selected. If possible I will need to know which is selected as I need the data to upload into the SQL.

```
protected void radioBtn_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if radiobutton is selected change  lbrQty and textQtyInput visible to true
}
```

*UPDATED*

Thank you for the help by adding AutoPostBack.

So let me go through what happen:

1. enter the barcode
2. radiobuttonlist appear <-- barcode must be valid
3. select and the QTY label and the textbox appear
4. enter a non valid barcode and the QTY label and textbox is still present. How do I get rid of them?

[Invalid barcode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sPzu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add and set the `AutoPostBack` property of the `RadioButtonList` to `true` to trigger your `radioBtn_SelectedIndexChange`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList
       ID="rediobtn"
       AutoPostBack="true"
       Font-Size="X-Small" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioBtn_SelectedIndexChange" 
       onclick="ShowHide(this)" 
       RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
       RepeatColumns="2" 
       runat="server">
```

When a radio is selected, make your `lbrQty` and `textQtyInput` visible:

```
protected void rediobtn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbrQty.Visible = true;
    textQtyInput.Visible = true;
}
```

When you're validating your barcode, hide your `lbrQty` and `textQtyInput` if the barcode in not valid:

```
lbrQty.Visible = false;
textQtyInput.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it seems to work.. in the If statement, my only condition is the  rationbutton must be selected thats all. Had another issue to trouble.

Comment: Please see my update: when you're validating your barcode, hide your controls if the barcode is not valid.